# Code editor with key authentication

Tags: security, ftp, webserver, sftp

I have been using Dreamweaver for many years simply because it has a built in FTP manager. This makes working on a website very efficient.

The code editor isn't all that great but I manage with it ok.

However I now have a problem in that Dreamweaver does not support key authentication on any of it's versions.

I am having to access a website that will only allow access using a key, passwords are off limits.

I have had a look around and there doesn't seem to be a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't really asked a direct question here; But I assume you're asking for a code editor which supports SFTP key auth?

In which case, [Coda 2](https://panic.com/coda/) has built in support for each type of connection (including key authentication).

If you're after a free alternative, I'd use [Cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io/) and [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/). If you open a file from Cyberduck (into Sublime Text), [it automatically uploads each time you save](https://trac.cyberduck.io/wiki/help/en/howto/edit).

If on the other hand you're looking for a way to use key authentication within Dreamweaver and the software simply doesn't support it, there's no way solve that.

Comment: Additionally, there is package in Sublime Text called [Sublime SFTP](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp) that support key authentication. The package cost $20, but you can use the free trial forever, it only shows a reminder to buy from time to time.